# MySQL Two Queries Producing One Value

Tags: php, mysql, date

I need to make a query that selects from two different tables. Basically, I only want to select the rows from the `dates` table that have no pending orders in the `orders` table.

For example, the `dates` table has the values of July 1, July 2 and July 3. July 2 has orders with the `status = PEN` in the `orders` table so the table will only show July 1 and July 3.

Query 1 for `dates`:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM dates WHERE DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), date) >= 30 AND `30day`='No'";
```

I have yet to build a query for the `orders` table as I am sure this needs to be integrated into one query together, and I am not sure what to do.

I know you can do two `SELECT` queries in one, and I am aware of how to do this, but I am unsure of how to cause the second `SELECT` query to be affected by the first `SELECT` query.

`dates` database has columns `id` `date` `closed` `30day` `60day`

`orders` database has columns `id` `date` `order` `status`

I need this query to flag any orders with the statuses `PEN` `BO` `FBO`.

Thank you in advance!

**Sample Data:**

`dates` table:

```
Date - 30-day Value

July 1 - No

July 2 - No

July 3 - No
```

`orders` table:

```
Date - Orders - Status

July 1 - 7123456 - PEN

July 1 - 7123457 - SHI

July 1 - 7123487 - SHI

July 2 - 7256789 - SHI

July 2 - 7256790 - SHI

July 2 - 7256791 - SHI

July 3 - 7215368 - SHI

July 3 - 7125369 - SHI

July 3 - 7659876 - BO

July 4 - 7569235 - FBO

July 4 - 7986585 - FBO
```

**Expected Result:**

```
Date

July 2

July 3
```

**Omitted Dates:**

```
Date - Reason

July 1 - because there is an open order

July 4 - because there is an open order
```

I don't want an omitted table - just wanted to show what wouldn't show up.

Comment: how about a left join? with a `group by` , a `having theCount=0`

Comment: Please provide more information on how your tables look like! (column names etc.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

could be this what you are looking for  (i don't know your schema so for the join i have used a column named key

```
$sql = "SELECT * 
         FROM dates
         LEFT JOIN orders on (dates.date = orders.date  and orders.status not in ('PEN','BO', 'FBO'))
         WHERE DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), dates.date) >= 30 
         AND `30day`='No'";
```

otherwise if you need that status is not PEN, BO and FBO then you can

..

```
$sql = "SELECT * 
        FROM dates 
        LEFT JOIN orders ON  dates.date = orders.date  
        WHERE DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), dates.date) >= 30 
        AND `30day`='No' 
        AND orders.status NOT IN ('PEN','BO', 'FBO'   ) ";
```

..

```
$sql = "SELECT * 
        FROM dates 
        INNER JOIN orders ON  dates.date = orders.date  
        WHERE DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), dates.date) >= 30 
        AND `30day`='No' 
        AND orders.status  IN ('PEN','BO', 'FBO'   ) ";
```

based on the sample provided  this should return the rows you need

```
 $sql = " SELECT * 
          FROM dates 
          WHERE DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), date) >= 30 
          AND `30day`='No' 
          AND date not in ( 
                        select date 
                        from orders 
                        where order.status  IN ('PEN','BO', 'FBO'   ) 
                      ) ";
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I updated my information including columns as I'm not 100% sure how to modify this query based on what you put, I am sorry. I am hoping you can assist.

Comment: @BrandinArsenault  i have update the answer using date for join .. hope is what  you need ..

Comment: do you have any recommendations based on my update to statuses. I need this to apply to statuses `PEN` `BO` `FBO`. Thank you!

Comment: In your question  you seem that need all the rows that match the data but that are <> 'PEN'   then with my answer you get  the rows that match for date but have status  = BO or FBO ..

Comment: I am sorry for the misunderstanding. I need the result to omit any dates that have corresponding orders with the status of `PEN` `BO` or `FBO`. I have up to 15 other statuses that are all "closed" type statuses that I do not want to count towards this query.

Comment: so you want all the order  that match the date and that are  not closed?

Comment: Correct - the non-closed statuses are `PEN` `BO` `FBO` - all other statuses are closed orders.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124751/discussion-between-brandin-arsenault-and-scaisedge).

Comment: I have update the answer  with a new versione  let me know

Comment: I fixed the fatal error by adding a bracket at the end of the not in section, you were missing one. The new update caused another fatal error. But now that I have it working with that revision, it is producing results with the statuses of PEN BO and FBO instead of the opposite.

Comment: then change the not in with in (remove not)

Comment: I did this and it is duplicating the date for EVERY order that has that date and is closed. I think we are getting there but maybe I am not advising properly. Currently is it producing a date for every closed order using the not in result, when I want it to completely omit that date from the result if there are ANY orders corresponding to that date that is open.

Comment: @BrandinArsenault   i have added  a new query with inner  join (eventually check if i repeat some sintax error)  if this not work you should update you queston with a proper data sample and the expected  result ..

Comment: the update is causing a fatal error again, and I am unable to replicate it, it is caused by 'Column 'date' in where clause is ambiguous'. I have updated my original post to include sample data and expected result. Thank you for your time, I appreciate this.

Comment: you are DARN GENIUS! If I could give you +1000 I would! Thank you!

Comment: thank you very much .. im happy when one my  answers are appreciated